# Researching Performance Degradation on AO Secondary using MultipleActiveResultSets (MARS)

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups

Environment: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition on Windows 6.3 9600 two node cluster with Always-On.

We have an application that executes SELECTs on the only secondary node of a SQL Server 2016 always-on availability group. That application uses the `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;MutlipleActiveResultSets=true` options in the connection string.

Query execution via the client's application is almost 50% slower on the secondary compared to the primary and we are trying to understand why. If I execute those same queries, using the same connection string via SSMS, the execution times are identical on both nodes.

**Some facts:**

- SQL Server has identical configurations and resources on both nodes.
- The network, VMWare configuration and proximity to the application
  server have been eliminated as potential causes

Reviewing wait statistics, there is this surprising information about transaction_mutex waits

[image]

and after some research, I found this [article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/transaction-mutex) which mentions excessive transaction_mutex waits when passing through MARS as is the case here.

There is also the very brief but consistent blocking behavior on the secondary which also seems to be a side effect of MARS.

[image]

Notice that the wait type is Transaction_Mutex when the blocking appears.

Questions:

1. Is using MARS to execute SELECTs on an Always-On Secondary Node causing these transaction_mutex waits and the additional execution time?
2. How do I track down the root cause?

Comment: FYI, you can't really test MARS behavior via SSMS the same way as app code uses it (e.g. interleave retrieval of SELECT results).